# Add drop down values to a CRM 2011 field using C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to add values to a CRM 2011's optionset via a C# application?

Comment: Are you talking about adding new values to the option set it self, or just updating the attribute option set value of an entity?

Comment: We are talking about adding new values to the option set itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These MSDN article, provide the code and examples for working with Global Option Sets

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509056.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509023.aspx

If you want to convert your local to global, [check this out](https://xrmoptionsetconverter.codeplex.com/):

If you want to create Local Option Sets (the example is in javascript, but the same requests exist in the C# library):

http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/03/working-with-optionset-values-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can set an option set value by:

```
OptionSetValue optionSet = new OptionSetValue();
optionSet.Value = 2; // optionset value is an integer
yourEntity["yourdropdown"] = optionSet;
```